# How to fixed button position in card footer in bootstrap 4?

Tags: button

[image]

In the left cart button is positioned in bellow as the text length is big. I want to set the button beside the like button. How can I fixed that with shrinking the text?

```
 $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo '<div class="col-sm-4">';
        echo '<div class="card">';
        echo '<div class="card-body"><a href="productDetails.php?id=';
        echo $row['code'];
        echo '"><img src="../';
        echo $row['imageurl'];
        echo '" class="img-responsive" style="width:250px;height:250px" alt="Image">';
        echo '</a></div><div class="card-footer">';
        echo $row['name'];
        echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark pull-right" onclick="like('.$row['code'].')"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark pull-right" onclick="cart('.$row['code'].')"><i class="fa fa-cart-arrow-down"></i></button></div></div></div>';
        $i++;
        $count--;
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can use add dots instead of shrinking the words like:

```
echo mb_strimwidth($row['name'], 0, 20, "...");
```